# Prevent from re-saving the same video in camera roll iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, video, save, share

My app allows users to create a video and share it on Facebook/Instagram or just save it in the camera roll,
but in order to share a video to this two social apps, I'll need to 
save the video in camera roll first.

But how do I prevent the user from re-saving the video?
(ex. Share to Facebook and then share again on Instagram,
the saveToCameraRoll() function will be called again.)

Comment: save to camera roll and then keep the asset path in a var ? you can use that var next time instead of re saving.